# Render CALayer using CARenderer into openGL 3.2

Tags: opengl, core-animation

I 'd like to render a CALayer into my openGL Context in openGL 3.2 Core.

I'm using CARenderer to render the layer but when I try to render I get the following error.

CoreAnimation: unsupported graphics hardware; need two or more texture units; need ARB_texture_rectangle extension; need EXT_framebuffer_object extension; need ARB shader extensions.

The problem doesn't occur when I ask for the legacy version of openGL. Is there a constant to pass to CARenderer in the rendererWithCGLContext:options: ?

Comment: I'm guessing that OpenGL 3.2 doesn't have the ARB_texture_rectangle extension because it's not even an extension anymore, it's part of core OpenGL.

Comment: yes I saw it in the apple documentation but I 'd like to find a way to tell my CARenderer that I'm using openGL 3.2 to ask him to use built-in GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE instead of ARB extension...[link]https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/UpdatinganApplicationtoSupportOpenGL3/UpdatinganApplicationtoSupportOpenGL3.html